# Bokeh Updating figure after number of columns have changed

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a source object `source = bokeh.models.ColumnDataSource(df)` that gets instantiated with a pandas DataFrame looking like

```
    Date           None   
0   2015-01-01     0  
1   2015-01-02     0  
2   2015-01-03     0  
3   2015-01-04     0  
4   2015-01-05     0 
5   2015-01-06     0  
6   2015-01-07     0
```

and I add a figure with a line plot for it, e.g.

```
f = figure(x_axis_type='datetime', title="Some line chart")
f.line("Date", "None", source=source)
```

Specifying the column names in `line()` that I want to be plotted is what actually bites me in the bottom.

When I update `source.data = source.from_df(new_df)` where `new_df` is a DataFrame with columns ("Date", "A", "B", "C"), then the figure will not be able to update because it expects columns ("Date", "None").

So what I tried was recreating the chart every time `source.data` is updated like so:

```
fig = figure(x_axis_type='datetime', title="Some line chart")
fig.line("Date", "None", source=self.source)
fig.line("Date", "NewCol", source=self.source)
self.charts.children[1].children[0].children[0] = fig
```

Please see the minimal example below for the exact code.

However, after updating the chart a couple of times I get:

```
2017-09-04 11:59:26,747 error handling message Message 'PATCH-DOC' (revision 1): 
RuntimeError('Cannot apply patch to 421a12b1-5880-409c-beec-5352ae014671 which is not in the document',)
```

Is there maybe a nicer way of doing this. Foreseeing which column names the `new_df` will ever contain is not very flexible I think. This would be last resort for me.

Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from bokeh.io import curdoc, gridplot
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.layouts import row, column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import (Panel, Tabs, Button)

class Main(object):
def __init__(self):

    index = pd.DatetimeIndex(start="2000-01-01", end="2000-02-01", freq="1d")
    df = pd.DataFrame({"None":np.repeat(0,len(index))},index=index)
    df.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
    df.columns = ["Date", "None"]

    source = ColumnDataSource(df)
    fig = figure(plot_width=700, plot_height=400, x_axis_type='datetime', title="Some chart")
    fig.line("Date", "None", source=source)

    self.df = df
    self.source = source
    self.fig = fig
    self.charts = gridplot([[fig]])

    btn = Button(label="Update", button_type="success")
    btn.on_click(self.update_linechart)

    tab = Panel(child=self.charts, title="Tab")
    tabs = Tabs(tabs=[tab])
    rows = row(tabs)
    self.cols = column(btn, rows)


def update_linechart(self):
    self.df.loc[:,"None"] = np.random.normal(size=len(self.df))
    self.df.loc[:,"NewCol"] = np.repeat(-1, len(self.df))
    self.source.data = self.source.from_df(self.df)

    print(self.charts.children[1].children[0].children[0])
    fig = figure(plot_width=700, plot_height=400, x_axis_type='datetime', title="Some chart")
    fig.line("Date", "None", source=self.source)
    fig.line("Date", "NewCol", source=self.source)
    self.charts.children[1].children[0].children[0] = fig


main = Main()
curdoc().add_root(main.cols)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = Main()
    curdoc().add_root(main.cols)
    main.update_linechart()
```